# TabBar as rootController flip animation

Tags: iphone, animation, tabbar, swipe

I'm using a TabBarController as the root controller for my app. I have all the views I use (5 tabs) all hooked together through it in interface builder.  What I'm trying to do is trigger a slide or flip animation when moving between tabs.  However, I only want this to occur when I change tabs programmatically (ie the animation is triggered when someone does a swipe gesture in the one of the views, but not when they just select one of the tabs).  The way I'm currently handling this is by calling:

```
[appDelegate.myTab setSelectedIndex:0];
```

when the iphone detects a swipe.  I've been searching the internet for 5 straight hours and can't seem to find a way to add an animation here.  It'd be really cool if there were something like:

[appDelegate.myTab setSelectedIndex:0 animated:(YES)];

However, there isn't...  I can't imagine no one's ever tried this before, but for the life of me, I can't find anything online that explains how this can be done.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I slept on this one and came up with an idea that seems feasible...  I thought I could created a container view that is 640x411.  In there, I could have both of my views side by side.  I could load that into the xib on one tab, and I could use the tabbar delegate to simply move my container view.  I could then add my animation to the container view...  I think this would work in theory, however when I tried this, I couldn't seem to enable touches on the embedded web views... any ideas?

Comment: Facing same problem.. found any work around ?